# autoassociative neural network Python

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, pybrain

I was trying to build an auto-associative artificial neural network with python.
I have tried to use the library pybrain. Here my code

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer

net = buildNetwork(20, 30, 2, 30, 20)

ds = SupervisedDataSet(20, 20)
for i in range(350):
    ds.addSample(data[i,:20], data[i,:20])

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)

for i in range(50):
    trainer.train()

net.activate(data[1,:20])
```

Ideas why doesn't learn correctly this small dataset? Can I use some other libraries? Am I doing something wrong

Comment: Did you try `trainer.trainUntilConvergence()`?

Comment: Yes and it takes forever to complete (doesn't finish at all)

Comment: It might be that 50 iterations are too few to learn decent weight, so it seems like it hasn't learned correctly. Multi-layer ANNs are more difficult to learn than algorithms based on a convex objective like SVM, logistic regression, least squares regression, etc.